# IIS: Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for all URLs

Tags: iis, https, redirect, http

For our website (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter, IIS 10) we use two different URLs - lets say `url1.com` and `url2.com` by using the same root directory and the same application pool.

In our web.config we define a redirection

```
<rules>
  <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true" xdt:Transform="Insert" >
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^localhost(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^127\.0\.0\.1(:\d+)?$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
  </rule>
</rules>
```

This works for all requests like `url1.com`, `http://url1.com` and `http://www.url1.com` but not for `url2.com`. Entering url2.com in our browser leads to `http://url2.com` and thus to error 403 .

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Some time of thinking solved our problem: The detailed (IIS) error number was 403.4 - SSL required. This means that my request was rejected already by IIS and did not reach our website. Thus, no redirect to https:// could be applied for `url2.com`.

In the IIS manager I found that for this URL "SSL required" had been selected. Unchecking this box solved my problem.